# Goertzel algorithm to get the phase?

Tags: algorithm, signal-processing

I am using Goertzel algorithm to get the amplitude of a certain frequency. 
I am trying now to get the phase from it, and I don't know how.

Can some one explain, and show me how to get the phase of a certain-f from this code?

Also, I am using it to 16khz, with sample rate 44.1. What's the smallest length of samples that I can run it on?

```
double AlgorithmGoertzel( int16_t *sample,int sampleRate, double Freq, int len )
{
    double realW = 2.0 * cos(2.0 * M_PI * Freq / sampleRate);
    double imagW = 2.0 * sin(2.0 * M_PI * Freq / sampleRate);
    double d1 = 0;
    double d2 = 0;
    double y;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        y=(double)(signed short)sample[i] +realW * d1 - d2;
        d2 = d1;
        d1 = y;
    }
    double rR = 0.5 * realW *d1-d2;
    double rI = 0.5 * imagW *d1-d2;

    return (sqrt(pow(rR, 2)+pow(rI,2)))/len;
}
```

Comment: I'm having problems understanding the last two results, `rR` and `rI`. Referring to the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goertzel_algorithm), are they the real and imaginary part of the quantity y(N) in eq. 11?

Comment: "Phase" makes no sense unless you specify a phase *relative* to something, e.g. to some other signal or to some absolute point in time. It would help if you explained what you're *really* trying to achieve here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [analyze audio in real time with narrow band-pass filter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13477448/analyze-audio-in-real-time-with-narrow-band-pass-filter)

Comment: @PaulR , in that forum i guess there aren't people that knows dsp- such as you, so , find a life, and dont jump without a basic understanding of my question,and if you found that as a duplicate, why didnt you answer the original question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the algorithm consists of multiplying the sequence by a constant, but by the complex signal `exp(n*i*2pi*freq/samplerate);` 0<=n<=length, and getting the average magnitude (or *power* of the signal).

As the complex output is R*exp(i theta), R gives the power at the given frequency and theta gives the phase. (theta == atan2 ( imag, real))

Comment: Phase relative to *what* though ? It would be completely arbitrary and meaningless in this context.

Comment: @PaulR phase does not have to be in relation to something, if you perform a bpsk , the phase is related to the previous phase . wish you could understand that .

Comment: The trick of the Goertzel algorithm is that it doesn't need to do many complex multiplications by exp(n*i*2pi*freq/samplerate), and instead operates with real numbers. Algorithm is correct. The question just needs to interpret the output correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Do a rectangular to polar conversion.  That will give you phase and magnitude.

magnitude = sqrt ((Vreal * Vreal) + (Vimag * Vimag))

phase = atan2 (Vimag, Vreal)

Answer (score 1):

The number of samples you need to feed a Goertzel filter will be inversely proportional to your desired or required filter bandwidth.  A Goertzel provides a Sinc shaped bandpass filter, with the main lobe width proportional to 2*Fs/N.

If you use a complex Goertzel, the resulting phase will be relative to some point in the filter's data window.  You may thus have to calculate an offset to get phase relative to some other reference point in time.

Comment: thanks, so if i give it 50 samples i get a nice bw of 1700hz , the problem is, that 50 is a lot, and i can miss a lot, unless i am running on ALL of my samples and not every 50 samples- which than makes Goerzel less better than FFT, is that right ?