# Definitive Goertzel algorithm implementation for phase?

Tags: algorithm, signal-processing

The [Goertzel Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goertzel_algorithm) is in widespread use for the likes of DTMF tone detection as a faster, more frequency-specific alternative to using an FFT. In that context and certain others, only the magnitude of the result matters, and so it does not matter whether one uses [this variation](http://www.embedded.com/design/configurable-systems/4024443/The-Goertzel-Algorithm) or [this variation](http://www.mstarlabs.com/dsp/goertzel/goertzel.html)  or [this variation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489519/goertzel-algorithm-to-get-the-phase).

But it matters a lot if you want to extract the phase from a signal. In each of these cases, the way `d1` and `d2` (or `q1` and `q2`) is combined is different, leading to completely different phase results. Moreover, none of them seem to agree with the spreadsheet simulation I have done in which I generate 100 samples of a sinewave of known frequency and phase, then use the Goertzel algorithm to detect that specific frequency (an integer multiple of the sampling frequency). What is clear is that when I vary the phase, the phase changes, but in none of these cases does a zero phase come out when I put a zero phase in.

So is any of these - or something else - the definitive implementation of the Goertzel Algorithm? I am used to an FFT giving me a zero phase out when I put a zero phase in. From what I read, the Goertzel Algorithm really should do the same. How do I get it to do this without some arbitrary offset?

Update: The Wikipedia page has a sum that runs from 0 to N, not just 0 to N-1. This could be a mistake, but if I extend my simulation by one step, I get a much more reasonable phase result... albeit exactly 90 degrees out of phase with the input phase. Is this a clue to where the answer lies?